# HighChart irrgular Mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created One HighChart ..But its 2 data coordinates are overlapping on y axis after every 2nd Coordinates.

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9xES/552/)

**My Code:**

```
$(function () {
    var highOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            renderTo: 'container2',
            zoomType: 'x',
            marginTop: 100

        },

        title: {
            text: 'Score'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: '  '
        },

        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'XXX'
            },
            categories: [],
            labels: {
                rotation: 45,
                step: 1,
                y: 30
            }
        },

        yAxis: [{ // left y axis
            title: {
                text: 'XXX'
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 9,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 7.5,
                color: '#ff0000',
                width: 2,
                zIndex: 4,
                label: {
                    text: 'XXX'
                }
            }]
        }],

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },
        series: []
    };


    highOptions.xAxis.categories = [0.1003, 0.1006, 0.1008, 1.1010, 1.1011, 1.1012, 1.1013, 2.4];

    highOptions.subtitle.text = "XXX:";
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions);

    for (var x = 0; x <= 1; x++) {
        var newLP = [];
        switch (x) {
            case 0:
                aName = "One";

                newLP.push([0.1004, 4.5]);
                newLP.push([0.1008, 1.4]);
                newLP.push([1.1012, 5.5]);
                newLP.push([1.1014, 2, 6]);
                newLP.push([2.4, 8.22]);

                break;
            case 1:

                aName = "Two";

                newLP.push([0.1004, 5.52]);
                newLP.push([0.1008, 6.16]);
                newLP.push([1.1012, 6.34]);
                newLP.push([1.1014, 6.69]);
                newLP.push([1.1016, 6.36]);
                newLP.push([2.4, 7.44]);
                break;
        }

        chart.addSeries({
            name: aName,
            data: newLP
        }, false);
    }
    chart.redraw();
});
```

I have test it with several data ..still it overlaps .. what could be the issue ..
Please Suggest

Comment: Do you mean that center points ovelaprs, and you cannot "hover" on top black point?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're x-axis points are so close to each other it seems as they are overlapping. For example `0.1003` is pretty close to `0.1006` and `0.1008` is pretty close to `1.1010`. However, If you zoom in you can tell they are not overlapping. See http://jsfiddle.net/u9xES/555/.

Comment: thank you sir for catching the real issue. I have seen updated fiddle code.. zoom property is still same .. Do I need to set it elsewhere ?

Comment: Hicharts tries to fit all your data into the screen. So I don't think that there is an easy way to set a default zoom level. The following are the options for zoomtypes http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType

Comment: sir but I mean you have set zoom in your jsFiddle ..But code is same as mine .How did you do that ..did you change any browser setting or anything else ?

Comment: All I did was to update the x-axis for the individual values                                 `newLP.push([0.1,4.5]);
newLP.push([0.2,1.4]);
newLP.push([1.0,5.5]);
newLP.push([1.3,2,6]);
newLP.push([2.4,8.22]);`

Comment: you can set the zoom level by setting the extremes of the chart. please refer to set extremes: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes